# Position of listitem items changes on scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have following code in which i am doing JSON parsing and showing results in listview.
The problem i am facing is whenever i am scroll the listview my listview contents position get changes for ex. if Accommodation is at 1st item in list, when i scroll down i can see accommodation again as a last item in the list or at any other position. My log-cat showing the proper result but not the listview.  I am not getting where i went wrong why my list not showing me proper result.

Comment: one minor change suggestion for your code : in CategoryAdapter's getItem function make it as return data.get(position);

Comment: @rajpara its still giving the same error, items are changing there position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow viewHolder pattern as below

```
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) 
        {
             holder = new ViewHolder();            
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_content, null);

             holder.name =  (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); 
             convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {     
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();     
        } 

        item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(item.get(CATEGORY_NAME));

        return convertView;




class ViewHolder
{
     TextView name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your getView like this if it help you..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_content, null);
     }

     name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
     item = new HashMap<String, String>();
     item = data.get(position);
     name.setText(item.get(CATEGORY_NAME));

    return convertView;
}
```